# What Technology I should use while developing a windows App

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, uwp

I'm new in Windows Apps Development.

App Requirements:
I need to develop windows app compatible for window7, window 8.1 and windows 10.
The app should Run on Windows Desktop and Tablets.

Can anyone please help me to choose, what platforms (like UWP, .NET, WPF, Windows RT etc)?

If there is any links and good tutorials available for me to get started, that would be also very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: UWP/WinRT won't run on Windows 7...

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your reply. Can you please got what platform I should go with? Do I need to go with WPF?

Comment: From your list, there's only one left that's compatible with all Windows versions: WPF

Comment: @Clemens  Thank you.

Comment: WPF is not a platform. It's a UI framework. The platform would be .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two choices:

1. .NET (C#. VB.NET and other) with [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).
2. JavaScript with [Electron JS](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/supported-platforms/)

In addition you'll get MacOS and Linux support if you choose Electron JS.

[UWP](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/getstarted) is only for Windows 10 [Mobile].

Comment: UWP is for any device running Windows 10. WinRT (Windows Runtime) is the foundation of UWP, introduced in Windows 8 (can be used to target Windows 8 and above). It is unrelated to Windows RT (the OS), which was available on Surface 1, and a few other devices only. Windows RT and Window Runtime (WinRT) are unrelated. Please fix your answer.